# VB.net, Conversion formato XML almacenado en Access

Tags: .net, xml, ms-access-2010

Estoy haciendo un programa en .net, el cual debe traer unos datos de Access y guardarlos en un archivo, entre esos datos se encuentra un XML, el cual cambia el formato al guardarlo en un archivo.
Código para buscar el XML:

```
  Public Function Buscar_XML()

    conecta()

    sql = New OleDbCommand("SELECT XML FROM TNR where TNR_NAME='" & Form1.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & "'", cnn)
    Reader = sql.ExecuteReader()

    Do While (Reader.Read())
        Form1.XML = Reader.GetValue(0)
    Loop


    Reader.Close()

    desconectar()
End Function
```

Crear el archivo:

```
  My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TNR\PRUEBA.xml", XML, False)
```

XML guardado en Access (copio un pequeño fragmento como ejemplo)

```
<body>
 <ENVELOPE>
  <OP_MSG_TYPE>SO</OP_MSG_TYPE>
  <OP_OPERATION>PUBLISH</OP_OPERATION>
```

Y esto es lo que guarda en el archivo.xml:

```
<div>&lt;body&gt;</div>

<div>   &lt;ENVELOPE&gt;</div>

<div>       &lt;OP_MSG_TYPE&gt;SO&lt;/OP_MSG_TYPE&gt;</div>

<div>       &lt;OP_OPERATION&gt;PUBLISH&lt;/OP_OPERATION&gt;</div>
```

Como puedo hacer para que me tome el valor tal cual esta en la BD, y por que sucede esto?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: pero el dato esta correctamente en la base de datos ? porque el problema no parece ser cuando recuperas sino cuando lo persistes

Comment: Hola, dentro del access se encuentra el formato correcto, el problema es al guardarlo en el archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias serializar una clase

```
Public Class ENVELOPE

   Public Property OP_MSG_TYPE As String
   Public Property OP_OPERATION As String

End Class
```

La idea es serializar el xml asignando los datos a la clase

```
Dim obj As New ENVELOPE

Dim mySerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ENVELOPE))

Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("myFileName.xml")
mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, myObject)
myWriter.Close()
```

Podrias generar el xml en memoria con un MemoryStream en lugar del StreamWriter para luego enviarlo a la db

En tu codigo tienes que usar parametros

```
Public Function Buscar_XML()

    conecta()

    Dim sql As New OleDbCommand("SELECT XML FROM TNR where TNR_NAME= @name", cnn)
    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Form1.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sql.ExecuteReader()

    Do While (reader.Read())
        Form1.XML = reader.GetValue(0)
    Loop

    reader.Close()

    desconectar()

End Function
```

Comment: Hola! para serializar debo declarar cada nodo del xml? el problema con eso es que son 21 XML guardados en el Access con mas de 1500 lineas cada uno y la idea es que se incremente la cantidad de XML. Muchas gracias